# how to convert date and time format in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have date and time format in this form:
`1628489237000`

I want in the below format:

DD/MM/YYYY and time.

I want to use that in javascript.

Comment: Why don't you use dayjs or moment like date library?

Comment: You can use moment.js to do that and more complex stuff https://momentjs.com/

Comment: I recommend using moment.js for everything related to dates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like this for date:

```
new Date(1628489237000).toLocaleDateString()
```

or for time:

```
new Date(1628489237000).toLocaleTimeString()
```

Comment: What about time?

Comment: `toLocaleTimeString()`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use library, I would like to recommend you [dayjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs)

with dayjs,

```js
dayjs().format('DD/MM/YYYY') // 10/08/2021'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var timestamp = 1607110465663;

var date = new Date(timestamp);
var month=''+date.getMonth();
var day=''+date.getDate();
if (month.length < 2) 
    month = '0' + month;
if (day.length < 2) 
    day = '0' + day;
console.log("Date: "+day+
      "/"+month+
      "/"+date.getFullYear()+
      " "+date.getHours()+
      ":"+date.getMinutes()+
      ":"+date.getSeconds());
```

if yout want to time to hh/mm/ss you can convert with condition "length"

Comment: You're missing logic to display dates and months as 2 digits.

Comment: oke bro . i just add logic to display dates and months as 2 digits.

Answer (score 0):

No need for any library for your case, especially not moment.js. You can read more about the project status [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)

```js
var timestamp = 1628489237000;

// Create date from timestamp
var date = new Date(timestamp);

// Format date
var formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString('fr');
var formattedTime = date.toLocaleTimeString('fr');

// Print results
console.log(formattedDate); // "09/08/2021"
console.log(formattedTime); // "8:07:17 AM"
console.log(`${formattedDate} ${formattedTime}`); // "09/08/2021 8:07:17 AM"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a solution that uses `momentjs` library:

```js
console.log(moment(1628489237000).format('DD/MM/YYYY'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")